# Why bundler doesn't use system gems?

Tags: ruby, bundler

Bundler version: `1.15.1`. Ruby version: `2.3.1`.
I have (from `gem env`):

```
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0
     - /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.3.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.3.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
```

With all the gems from Gemfile.lock present under `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0`. But bundler will not try to re-use these and instead will attempt to redownload every time.

My `.bundle/config`:

```
    ---
    BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
    BUNDLE_BIN: "vendor/bin"
    BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "true" <--- removing this config entry doesn't help
```

running `bundle install` just re-downloads the gems instead of saying 'Using' so takes a long time.

What are the settings that might cause this and how to make the bundler get gems from system path `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0`?

I have read the bundle and bundle install docs fully but can't see how I can make bundler use the system gems. Other than using `source 'file:///var/lib/gems/2.3.0'` after generating an index, but I would really like to avoid this and use a more elegant solution. Especially since it would probably cause the gems to be re-installed which takes even more time than re-download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS` to `true`. This setting instructs bundler to specifically ignore any system-installed gems. Instead, bundler downloads all required gems into your `BUNDLE_PATH`.

If you want to use system-installed gems if appropriate, remove the `BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS` setting from your bundle config.

Comment: Only now I have noticed that after deleting this entry, it re-appears automatically! So when I delete it from the file, upon running `bundle install`, it gets added into the file right away.

Comment: Got that bit now. `bundle install` will do this whenever it is made to not install gems into system path (so the `BUNDLE_PATH` and `BUNDLE_BIN` settings). I'll stop short of comment about what I think about that. Thank you for the help!